# Sharepoint 2013 not displaying lookup field as input

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I have a lookup column whose datasource has many items (2 000+) and when creating an item that references the source list, a dropdown is not very suited for the task. In SP2010 when there were more than 20 items the lookup column control was rendered as an input with autosuggest.

How do i enable this feature in SP 2013/Online?